# How do I imitate useEffect using componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am more familiar with functional components, but I have to fix some class components that were built earlier. What I am trying to do is,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (state1) {
        // do this
        // change state state1 -> false
    }
}, [state1])
```

something like this in a class component. What I tried was

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.state1 !== this.props.state1) {
      if (nextProps.state1) {
          // do this
      } else {
        // revert this
      }
      // update state
      this.setState({ state1: !this.state.state1 });
    }
  }
```

Obviously, this is weird. But I was confused because the `componentWillReceiveProps` receives a `prop` as a parameter. So, I am not sure how I am supposed to put in a state to detect changes in states.

Any help?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is probably not the right tool. Are you open to solutions that use other lifecycle functions, or do you have a need to use componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks for the reply. I am open to any solutions that would work in a class component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use componentDidUpdate, not componentWillReceiveProps. [componentWillReceiveProps is going to be removed from react](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), and it often gets misused.

With componentDidUpdate, you will do something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.state1 !== prevState.state1) {
    if (this.state.state1) {
      // do this
      // change state state1 -> false
      this.setState({ state1: false });
    }
  }
}
```

You may need to do similar code in componentDidMount if you need this code to run after the first render too.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, I cannot reach the inner condition. Do I have to move the setState to the outer loop?